# Reference data from one MySQL table by using a field from another

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create an HTML table using PHP and MySQL. I have 2 MySQL tables, named `coffees`, and `suppliers`, seen here:

**Coffees**:

[image]

**Suppliers**:
[image]

In my HTML table, I wish to display the *coffee name*, *supplier name*, and *total*.
My problem however, is that in order to display the supplier name, I must use the `SUP_ID` field from the `coffees` table to reference `SUP_NAME` from the `suppliers` table.

My final output aims to be something along the lines of this:
[image]

My code is the following:

```
<?php

$connection_var = new mysqli("server", "user", "pw", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connection failed: s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}

$coffees = "SELECT * from coffees";
$suppliers = "SELECT * from suppliers";

$coffeesArr = mysqli_fetch_array($coffees);
$supplierArr = mysqli_fetch_array($suppliers)
    
echo("<br>");
echo("<table border='1'>");
echo("<tr><td>COF_NAME</td><td>SUPPLIER NAME</td><td>TOTAL</td></tr>");

foreach($resultArr as $row) {
    echo("<tr>");
    echo("<td>" . $row['COF_NAME'] . "</td><td>" . /* Supplier name (from 2nd table) */ . "</td><td>" . $row['TOTAL'] . "</td><td>");
    echo"</tr>");
}

mysqli_close($connection_var);
?>
```

As seen above, I can easily reference the `COF_NAME` and `TOTAL` fields from the first table, however I am at a loss at how to reference the `SUP_NAME` field from my 2nd MySQL table, as it would require me to use the `SUP_ID` field from the first table. I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me on how to achieve this.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php

Comment: Try to use a **JOIN** instead of making two queries. That is what relational databases are made for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make an INNER JOIN so it joins both tables

```
<?php

$connection_var = new mysqli("server", "user", "pass", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connection failed: s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT c.cof_name, s.sup_name, c.total FROM COFFEES c INNER JOIN suppliers s ON c.cof_id=s.sup_id";

$result  = mysqli_query($connection_var, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection_var));

echo("<br>");
echo("<table border='1'>");
echo("<tr><th>COF_NAME</th><th>SUPPLIER NAME</th><th>TOTAL</th></tr>");;
    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result ,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo("<tr>");
    echo("<td>" . $row['cof_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['sup_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>");
    echo("</tr>");
}

mysqli_close($connection_var);

?>
```

[Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgX6A.png)

For more MySQL documentation about the joins: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: If the main focus of this Database is **to request information from the database (OLAP)** you should keep the table the **denormalized as possible**.
--
"Denormalization is a technique in which we add the duplicate data to one or more table. With the help of this, we can avoid costly joins in a relational database. Denormalization is a technique to speed up read oriented data retrieval performance in a relational database"
--
Documentation: [https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=design-denormalization-tables]

Answer (score 1):

A simple `INNER JOIN` is needed:

```
select c.cof_name,
       s.sup_name,
       c.total
from coffees c 
inner join suppliers s on c.sup_id=c.sup_id;
```

> Lear more about [MySQL
> alias](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)
>
> Check MySQL different types of joins:
>
> [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html